# Embed NavigationToolbar in separate frame than FigureCanvas with wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython

I would like to add the `matplotlib.backends.backends_wx.NavigationToolbar2Wx` to a GUI I'm developing, but I would rather not have it on the `FigureCanvas`, since it would force my layout to be rather awkward.  Is there a way to add the `NavigationToolbar2Wx` to a different part of the GUI than the canvas that it is attached to?  In particular, I would like the following layout

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                                                                    | |
| |                                                                    | |
| |                                                                    | |
| |                                                                    | |
| |                            FigureCanvas                            | |
| |                                                                    | |
| |                                                                    | |
| +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
| +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
| |  TextCtrl   TextCtrl        NavToolbar           TextCtrl  Button  | |
| +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
|                                                                        |
|                               More GUI here                            |
|                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where the `FigureCanvas` and the section below it are in the same vertical `BoxSizer`, and the region with the `NavigationToolbar` is a horizontal `BoxSizer`.

I've attempted various things, such as the obvious construct the toolbar, set the sizer to the horizontal `BoxSizer`, and add it to the `BoxSizer`, but it doesn't draw (although the `InspectionTool` will highlight where it should be`, and when I close the window it throws a segfault.  If I don't set the sizer for the toolbar, the behavior is identical except it doesn't throw a segfault.  I am making sure to call`.Realize()`and`.Update()` on the toolbar, but so far I've had no luck.

Is what I want to do even possible, or will I have to implement the buttons and behavior manually?

Comment: This is possible in the Qt embedding, so I would assume you can do it with WX.  Can you show us the code you are using to generate the gui (as simplified as possible please!).  Have you looked at the slew of wx examples at http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/?

Comment: @tcaswell it'll take me a while to get a real code example up, but I have looked at the wx examples on matplotlib.org, and I've googled around quite a bit trying to find a solution.  I have another working project where the toolbar is in the same panel as the canvas, and I think that might be the key difference between the two.  It's also interesting to me that the `NavigationToolbar2Wx` doesn't take a parent argument, while the Qt version does.

Comment: As a disclaimer, I know nothing about Wx except to point people at those examples.

Comment: @bheklilr: Have you looked at matplotlib's wx_backend.py?  I don't think this capability is in there (ie, different panels for the fig and nav), and I don't know enough about matplotlib's working to know whether it's possible, but if it is, using wx_backend.py is the place to start.

Comment: @bheklilr: I have done this before. Since the provided toolbar is lacking in functionality and looks, I just made my own in the usual way. You have to set the `NavigationToolbar2Wx` to point to the canvas, then `realize` and `Hide` it. The new toolbar callbacks just call the hidden toolbar methods, i.e. `panel.toolbar.zoom()`. If interested I can make this into a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, this is an almost :-) working example, with the trivial parts left out. I have used `wx.lib.agw.buttonpanel` as my toolbar, but of-coarse anything else will work as well.

```
import wx.lib.agw.buttonpanel as BP
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx


#---------------------------- plot panel -----------------------------
class PanelWithCanvas(wx.Panel):
    """
    This panel contains plot figure and other things...
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = frame

        ...

        # create figure
        self.figure = plt.Figure()
        self.axes  = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.grid()
        # attach a canvas to the figure
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, wx.ID_ANY, self.figure) 

        # create the default matplotlib toolbar and attach it to the canvas
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(self.canvas)
        # realize and hide it, since it will be replaced by a better one
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.toolbar.Hide()

        # create a new plot toolbar to replace the default one
        self.ptb = plotToolbar(self)

        ...


#---------------------------- plot toolbar -----------------------------
class plotToolbar(BP.ButtonPanel):
    """
    Create small toolbar which is added to the main panel
    par:  parent
    """
    def __init__(self, par):
        BP.ButtonPanel.__init__(self, par)

        # PanelWithCanvas
        self.pwc = par

        self.ID_FIT = wx.NewId()
        self.ID_ZOOM = wx.NewId()
        self.ID_PAN = wx.NewId()
        self.ID_SAVE = wx.NewId()

        self.AddSpacer()

        btn1 = BP.ButtonInfo(self, self.ID_FIT, bitmaps['zoomfit'].GetBitmap(),
                         shortHelp='Fit plot extents')
        self.AddButton(btn1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ZoomFit, btn1)

        self.btnzoom = BP.ButtonInfo(self, self.ID_ZOOM, bitmaps['zoom'].GetBitmap(),
                         kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK, shortHelp='Zoom in/out')
        self.AddButton(self.btnzoom)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Zoom, self.btnzoom)

        self.btnpan = BP.ButtonInfo(self, self.ID_PAN, bitmaps['pan'].GetBitmap(),
                         kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK, shortHelp='Move plot')
        self.AddButton(self.btnpan)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Pan, self.btnpan)

        btnsav = BP.ButtonInfo(self, self.ID_SAVE, bitmaps['saveimage'].GetBitmap(),
                         shortHelp='Save image')
        self.AddButton(btnsav)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveImage, btnsav)

        self.AddSpacer()

        self.DoLayout()

    def ZoomFit(self, event):
        self.pwc.toolbar.home()
        event.Skip()

    def Zoom(self, event):
        self.pwc.toolbar.zoom()
        event.Skip()

    def Pan(self, event):
        self.pwc.toolbar.pan()
        event.Skip()

    def SaveImage(self, event):
        self.pwc.toolbar.save_figure(None)
        event.Skip()
```

Please note that you will have to manage the behavior of the buttons yourself, since some of them are push only (fit-all, save), some are toggle (zoom, pan) and are mutually exclusive as well... or you can just leave them all as push buttons as in `NavigationToolbar2Wx`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @bheklilr - Did this answer help you at all? If so please accept it for future reference :-)

Comment: Why do you not include "the trivial parts"? Just makes it harder to run your example to quickly see if what you are doing is what other users want or not.

Comment: @JonathanLindgren oh that was long time ago… anyhow the parts left out are the sizers and layout of the figure in the frame, it should be easy enough for someone looking to embed a toolbar. i did it to make the answer shorter and easier to understand. i think you have a good point there about running the code quickly though